# Measuring frequency of change in time series data with inconsistent time intervals?

Tags: time-series, unevenly-spaced-time-series

**Context**

I'm tracking auction house prices for items in Guild Wars 2 in a database. They provide an [API](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/API:2/commerce/prices) that allows me to get the item's current buy/sell offer quantities and prices at that moment. As a result I have a time series of this data stored in my database at irregular intervals.

**Average & Standard Deviation Not Quite What I Need**

I started out using an average and standard deviation to determine which items to buy/sell. My problem is that neither of those include the time between quantities. I want to know how often the buy/sell quantities are changing and that they are in-fact changing, not necessarily by how much.

**How to Measure Frequency of Change in Aggregate?**

Ultimately, I want to be able to know if an item's supply/demand is constantly changing from 100 to 99 and potentially back to 100. If I have a bunch of quantities over time that are 100 and 99, that doesn't give me an impression of how often the data is changing at an aggregate-level.

Is there some sort of formula, measure, or other solution that can help give me an impression of how often the quantities change at an individual item level? I don't care by how much it changes it could go from 99 to 1,000,000 for all I care, I just want to know that it's changing frequently, slowly, or not at all.

Also, will the irregular time intervals matter?

[image]

Comment: A lot depends on how much data is available, and what it looks like. Maybe if you provide some, someone might be able to help.

Comment: I added a picture of what the data looks like. It's basically 4 integers and a timestamp associated with an itemID. Not sure if that's what you meant or not. Currently I have 300K records for just today.

Comment: A bit. I cannot say I understand the data or what information you want to extract from it. The data looks sort of wild, jumping all over the place. How can supply and demand have such highly variable numbers from one instant to the next? What does it mean?

Comment: You might be interested in the Autoregressive Conditional Duration model. Irregular data change the modelling quite a bit, though I suspect there are some simple strategies to take advantage of the « bursts » of activity.

Comment: @Carl, the "supply" and "demand" are actually sell and buy requests in an auction house . So, you could create a request to buy an item for some amount of currency, but then cancel that request (or have that request be fulfilled) a second or two later. The quantities are based on the number of requests for that price at the moment they were requested.

Comment: @MaximilianAigner I'll look that up and see if it helps, thanks!